How can i optimizate Djnago ORM request?
how can optimize the ORM request, getting the GDD takes a lot of time. I think problem with subquery, but through realation "commune__communemeteo" it takes even longer, (communemeteo about 1 million).
  communes = communes.filter(
       communeattribute__date__year=year,
       communeattribute__date__month=month,
       communeattribute__date__day__range=(
           days.get("start_date"),
           days.get("end_date"),
       ),
   )
   gdd_subquery = (
       CommuneMeteo.objects.filter(
           date__range=(start_date, end_date), commune_id=OuterRef("id")
       )
       .values("commune_id")
       .annotate(gdd=Sum((F("temp_min") + F("temp_max")) / Value(2) - Value(TBASE)))
       .values("gdd")[:1]
   )

   communes = communes.annotate(
       plant=Value(f"{plant}", output_field=CharField()),
       size=Sum(F("communeattribute__planted_area"), output_field=FloatField()),
       gdd=Subquery(gdd_subquery, output_field=FloatField()),
   )

models.py

class CommuneMeteo(models.Model):
   date = models.DateField(db_index=True)
   commune = models.ForeignKey(Commune, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_index=True)
   temp_min = models.FloatField()
   temp_avg = models.FloatField()
   temp_max = models.FloatField()
   precip_total = models.FloatField()

class Commune(models.Model):
   geometry = models.MultiPolygonField(geography=True)
   code = models.CharField(max_length=20)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   region = models.ForeignKey(Region, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_index=True)
   sub_region = models.ForeignKey(
       SubRegion, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, db_index=True, null=True, blank=True
   )
   ```


I don't have your models, I struggle to write the code. you have to use in your queryset select_related() for your FK fields or prefetch_related() for manytomany
    CommuneMeteo.objects.select_related('your_fk_fields',).filter(
       date__range=(start_date, end_date), commune_id=OuterRef("id")
   )
   .values("commune_id")
   .annotate(gdd=Sum((F("temp_min") + F("temp_max")) / Value(2) - Value(TBASE)))
   .values("gdd")[:1])

Another thing I can suggest is to use Pandas and Numpy if you have big data. You will spend some time studying, but it is not wasted time I can assure you.

i added models. select_related doesn`t need

@kirill  QuerySet.select_related() and prefetch_related()¶
Use them everytime you can, Your code is well typed, the problem is the big data you have. The ORM queryset has limit to work with big data. It is the numpy and Pandas job , that's why they are so popular in python. I'm sorry to have to suggest you study a new library
